# How to combine the two rows of a dataset into a single row in spark using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

> I am reading the transactions from a kafka topic in json format. then
>   i applied some transformations to get the aggregations based on the
>   txn_status .   Below is the schema.
>
> root  |-- window: struct (nullable = true)  |    |-- start: timestamp
>   (nullable = true)  |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)  |--
>   txn_status: string (nullable = true)  |-- count: long (nullable =
>   false)
>
> My batch output is like below after applying grouping for the given
>   window. [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> but i want the output like below json format.
>
> ```
> {
>        “start_end_time”: “28/12/2018 11:32:00.000”,
>        “count_Total” : 6
>        “count_RCVD” : 5,
>        “count_FAILED”: 1
>   }
>
>
> > how to combine two rows in a spark dataset.
> > 
> > 
> >   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCJuX.jpg
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As per the image you have shown, I have created a data frame or a temp table and provided the solution for your question.

Scala Code:

```
case class txn_rec(txn_status: String, count: Int, start_end_time: String)

var txDf=sc.parallelize(Array(new txn_rec("FAIL",9,"2019-03-08 016:40:00, 2019-03-08 016:57:00"), 
    new txn_rec("RCVD",161,"2019-03-08 016:40:00, 2019-03-08 016:57:00"))).toDF

txDf.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")

var resDF=spark.sql("select start_end_time, (select sum(count) from temp) as total_count , (select count from temp where txn_status='RCVD') as rcvd_count,(select count from temp where txn_status='FAIL') as failed_count  from temp group by start_end_time")

resDF.show

resDF.toJSON.collectAsList.toString
```

You can see the output as shown in the screen shot.

[image: Output-1]

[image: Output-2]

Comment: Thanks you. I am new to spark. I want to use Dataset to impliment this in java, i didn't find parallelize in dataframe functions. Can we get it done in java.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how input batch data is represented? How you want to convert into output.